# How to determine if change in time series is noise or significant?

Tags: time-series, change-point

I am looking at weekly sales data and see that sales last week dropped by x%. I see that weekly sales do fluctuate quite a bit so not sure if this is indeed a problem. What statistical methods can I use to determine if the observed change is something I should worry about.
One option could be to plot the pct change for the last 52 weeks as a histogram (or distribution) and see where x% change falls in that distribution. If the likelihood of observed change is less than 5%, then I can conclude that the change is not due to noise but rather something that needs investigation. However, I am not sure if this approach would hold true given that these data points are not independent of each other as they are points in time series. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Link through the tags I added for some ideas.  However, if your situation is exactly as you write, any result you obtain can legitimately be characterized as data snooping: after observing some interesting result, you formulated a procedure or test to "verify" it, casting doubt on the significance.  It's hard to defend against that unless you can adduce other information that would independently suggest that test. For instance, if the week before you had started a sales campaign, the natural approach would be a comparison of post-campaign results to pre-campaign results.

Comment: You may want to look at something called 'online changepoint detection'. I am not particularly familiar with the following R package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ocp/vignettes/introduction.html) but it might be what you are interested in.